# Custom Model Binder for a base class in Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, custom-model-binder

given the following models

```
public class RequestBase
{
    public DateTime TransactionTimestamp { get; set; }

    public Guid RequestMessageId { get; set; }

}

 [ModelBinder(typeof(RequestBaseModelBinder))]
public class StandardRequest : RequestBase
{

     public Guid MyGuidId { get; set; }

    public int MyIntId { get; set; }

}
```

The values in the `RequestBase` are sent via headers so i'm trying to implement a custom model binder to bind them to the model

This is what I've got so far

```
 public class RequestBaseModelBinder :IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var requestBase = bindingContext.Model as RequestBase;

        if (requestBase != null)
        {
            requestBase.RequestMessageId =
               Guid.Parse(actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("RequestMessageId").FirstOrDefault());

            requestBase.TransactionTimestamp =
               DateTime.Parse(actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("TransactionTimestamp").FirstOrDefault());

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

It is not working at the moment as the `bindingContext.Model` is null

Answer (score 1):

No, bindingContext.Model is the object that you will get from your action parameter.

You should get your headers from actionContext.Request, build a model ,and set your model to bindingContext.Model

code should like:

```
Dictionary<string, string> kvps = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Query))
        {
            kvps = actionContext.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().ToDictionary(a=>a.Key,a=>a.Value);
        }
        //Check and get source data from body 
        else if (actionContext.Request.Content.IsFormData())
        {
            var bodyString = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            try
            {
                kvps = ConvertToKvps(bodyString);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, "No input data");
            return false;
        }
        Object obj = null;

        try
        {
            obj = new Something(kvps);//build your object by key value pairs
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(
                bindingContext.ModelName, ex.Message);
            return false;
        }

        bindingContext.Model = obj;
        return true;
```

see this example:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/701182/A-Custom-Model-Binder-for-Passing-Complex-Objects